# FIND_IN_SET in mysql query for double condition

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this

```
products : id , name , groups , domains
```

Here groups and domains are both comma seperated fields. I am working on an existing project and i can not change the structure. Here is the detail.

```
groups : id , name
domains : id , name
```

products

```
id      |   name    |   groups  |   domains
------------------------------------------------
1       |   A       |   1,2,3   |   0
2       |   B       |   1,2,3   |   0   
3       |   C       |   1,2,3   |   1,2 
4       |   D       |   2,3     |   1,3 
5       |   E       |   2,3     |   2,3 
6       |   F       |   2,3     |   2,3,4   
7       |   G       |   1,2,3   |   0   
8       |   H       |   1,2,3   |   0   
9       |   I       |   2,3     |   1,2,4   
10      |   J       |   3       |   1,3 
11      |   K       |   3       |   2,4 
12      |   L       |   3       |   2,3 
13      |   M       |   1,2,3   |   0   
14      |   N       |   1,2,3   |   0   
15      |   0       |   3       |   1,2,4
```

domains

```
id  |   name
---------------------
1   |   yahoo   
2   |   gmail
3   |   mailinator
4   |   hotmail
```

groups

```
id  |   name
---------------------
1   |   General 
2   |   Contractor
3   |   Partner
```

Now i need to select all those which have these conditions.
How can i select products where

```
groups : 3
domains : 1
```

Note 0 means all(1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a shame you cannot modify this, and +1 for wishing you were able to.  But you have the right idea using `FIND_IN_SET()` . The only other thing to consider is an `OR` condition to account for the `0` (all) value. Give each condition the option of satisfying `FIND_IN_SET()` or being equal to `0`.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(3, groups)
    OR groups = 0)
    AND (FIND_IN_SET(1, domains)
      OR domains = 0)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc73/4)

Comment: Well thanks for your help i was only missing an OR. groups can not be zero only domains can be 0. Thanks by the way i understand how to handle from now on.